# type hinting a function that takes the return type as parameter

Tags: python, type-hinting

Is there a way to type hint a function that takes as argument its return type? I naively tried to do this:

```
# NOTE:
# This code does not work!
#
# If I define `ret_type = TypeVar("ret_type")` it becomes syntactically 
# correct, but type hinting is still broken.
#
def mycoerce(data: Any, ret_type: type) -> ret_type
    return ret_type(data)

a = mycoerce("123", int)  # desired: a type hinted to int
b = mycoerce("123", float)  # desired: b type hinted to float
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic), especially [TypeVar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). You can do something like this:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Callable

R = TypeVar("R")
D = TypeVar("D")

def mycoerce(data: D, ret_type: Callable[[D], R]) -> R:
    return ret_type(data)

a = mycoerce("123", int)  # desired: a type hinted to int
b = mycoerce("123", float)  # desired: b type hinted to float

print(a, b)
```

Comment: `ret_type` is surely `Type[T]` (e.g. `int`) not just `T` (e.g. `123`)? https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type

Comment: Good point. @japs needs to answer this question.

Comment: Do they? Just look at the example implementation: `return ret_type(data)`. `ret_type` needs to be called with `data` and return `T`; `Callable[[Any], T]` would work, for example: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=526d090e1a7a3354964fc28dbb268663.

Comment: You are right. Missed that. One could further improve your hint by replacing `Any` by another `TypeVar` to ensure `data` has the same type as the `ret_type` callable. I will update my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I oversimplified my minimal example. In general `ret_type` needs not be a callable, albeit I had in mind to pass a class as `ret_type`, which is indeed a callable. But your hints (pun intended) definitely pointed in the right direction. Thanks both!